# partial deserialization with protobuf

Tags: design-patterns, serialization, architecture, protobuf-net

To marc or anyone who's experienced in protobuf-net:

I have an architecture where the server holds life-long persistent connections to clients (over TCP). Because the connection layer/server should have high uptime, it only de-serializes messages and passes them to app server/layer. It contains no biz logic itself.

```
 clients -> connection layer (deserialization) -> app layer (business logic)
```

Problem is that while I can now make changes to the biz logic, I can NOT change the model shared by the app layer and clients, because the connection layer relies on the model for de-serialization.

Is there any way to have the connection layer only PARTIALLY deserialize the messages to a base class, for forwarding/routing purposes?

Otherwise, I guess I'll have to create a binary field within the base class that is passed on as is and gets deserialized by the app layer. One stage serialization, two stage de-serialization.

**EDIT: fleshed out**

```
class Message
{
  User user;
  // not much else in here, potentially routing information
}

class RequestType1: Message
{
 // lots of fields 
 // which are specific to this type of request/reply 
}

class RequestType2: Message
{

}
```

The connection layer should not care about the structure of specific request types. That way I can change them at will, as long as both the client and app layer agree. But currently the connection layer does the deserialization so it DOES need to know the model, and any changes force me to restart the connection server.

I just need it to deserialize enough to route, which means 'user information' + 'subtype name/number'.

Comment: i guess another option is to create a deserialization/routing layer between the connection layer and application layer. this is partly a design question, rather than just a protobuf question.

Comment: Can you flesh this out a bit, I.e. an example of the full message (a small one, preferably), and info on what fields etc you want for the partial deserialization? Also, if you *do* partially deserialize, what you would pass downstream - the original full message? Etc. Happy to help, but need more context.

Comment: Have a look now, maybe it makes more sense.

Comment: and what are you passing downstream? The original byte[]? Or...? Or the partially constucted object and the rest of the Stream? Or...? Also: how big are the messages? If they aren't huge, then frankly embedding a byte[] may be the *simplest* option. I can think of a handful of ways of doing this, but to give the most appropriate I want to make sure. For example, a very practical option would be to simply store 2 messages sequentially, using the WithLengthPrefix options. The first would be the routing, the second would be the actual payload...

Comment: Messages are 50-1000 bytes, mean 400. The original byte[] downstream works. Currently routing is based on subtype (e.g. RequestType1) so ideally no additional routing information to be added. I guess I can go with embedding byte[] + subtype name stored as string for routing.

Comment: Hmm WithLengthPrefix looks interesting. I can also not involve protobuf and add a few bytes myself before each message for routing. OK I think I have enough options now to go ahead. I'll just upvote your comments... thx!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all: You should not send protobuf serialized messages directly over the wire since TCP is stream based. You can never tell when you have received a complete message.

The `WithLengthPrefix` is used for just that. To prefix all messages with a binary length so that you can tell when a complete message has arrived.

If I were you I would create a header which contains enough information for the routing. The length is mandatory but you can also include the type of the transported message etc. That means that you only have to inspect the header for each message instead of invoking a costly deserialization.

Example request header:

- header version (`byte`)
- content type (`byte`) (you need to create a mapping somewhere)
- content length (`int`)

I'm currently writing a small addon for my Griffin.Networking ( http://github.com/jgauffin/griffin.networking) which will have a small header and use protobuf for the messages. Watch the project to get an update when it's committed.

Comment: Yeah, I already had a size prefix and now added a routing header. Will accept your answer as marc did not post one and you spent some time writing it. Cheers.

Comment: That's a shame if that's still current. With strongly defined data contracts it's feasible to have streaming serialization and un-preknown message length. I have achieved this with JSON and am currently switching to BinaryWriter with that same feature. The benefit is obviously lower peak memory usage and also shorter lead-times associated with waiting for the message to be built. The challenge with such an interface though is ensuring the deserialized stream is consumed in the correct order if there are multiple enumerable sections. (Implemented in C# with IEnumerable<> and yield)